# Creating an SVG graphic that moves coordinates rather than stretch itself when resized

Tags: html, svg

So we all know that we can set an SVG to not respect its aspect ratio when resized, that's all good. But I have a very simple SVG graphic that I need to stretch over to 100% of my browser window's width while keeping the same height (It's a header). The only thing I can do is resize it, but instead of moving the coordinates, it stretches, causing wider strokes and ugly diagonals. Is there any way to achieve what I want with SVG?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please add essential parts of your code. Read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for asking a better received question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a svg property to prevent strokes from stretching gimme a sec to look it up.

Found it, adding the attribute to a svg path should prevent the strokes from stretching: vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"

Had to look it up myself a while back while working on graphs: http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/1234041-svg-line-graph/